# How to create a grid like this in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, grid

I created a grid using the code in react. I have two pieces like `Black-queen` and `white-queen`.
`Black-queen` only needs to move in a even column and row (i.e. white background cells) and `white-queen` only needs to move in an odd column and row (i.e., dark grey background cells).

```
function Board() {
  const [gridCells, setGridCells] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log("King is clicked!", id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const TOTAL = 19 * 19;
    const newGridCells = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++) {
      const row = Math.floor(i / 19);
      const col = i % 19;
      const colorClassName = row % 2 === 1 || col % 2 === 1 ? "red" : "green";

       newGridCells.push(
          <div
            key={i}
            id={`${row}_${col}`}
            className={`grid-cell ${colorClassName}`}
            chess="null"
            onClick={() => handleClick(`${row}_${col}`)}
          />
        );
    }

    setGridCells(newGridCells);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="GridContainer" className="colored-grid">
      {gridCells}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is what I tried in the code above, and I want to create grid in the image below. [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoZFa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what problem you have.

Based on your code, I think you are having almost everything in red.

Try changing

```
const colorClassName = row % 2 === 1 || col % 2 === 1 ? "red" : "green";
```

to

```
const colorClassName = row % 2 === col % 2 ? "red" : "green";
```

This ensures odd rows match odd columns and even rows match even columns.

Besides that, why don't you use nested loops instead of re-calculating row and column ids?

```js
const newGridCells = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
 
 for (let j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
  const colorClassName = i % 2 === j % 2 ? "1" : "0";
  newGridCells.push(
      <div
        key={i}
        id={`${i}_${j}`}
        className={`grid-cell ${colorClassName}`}
        chess="null"
        onClick={() => handleClick(`${i}_${j}`)}
      />
    );
 }

}
```

Comment: I want the output like in the image.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Board() {
  const [gridCells, setGridCells] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log('King is clicked!', id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const TOTAL = 19 * 19;
    const newGridCells = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++) {
      const row = Math.floor(i / 19);
      const col = i % 19;
      const colorClassName = row % 2 === 1 || col % 2 === 1 ? 'red' : 'green';

      newGridCells.push(
        <div
          key={i}
          id={`${row}_${col}`}
          className={`grid-cell ${colorClassName}`}
          chess="null"
          onClick={() => handleClick(`${row}_${col}`)}
          style={{
            width: '20px',
            height: '20px',
            background: row % 2 === 0 && col % 2 === 0 ? "#bbb" : row % 2 === 0 || col % 2 === 0 ? "#ddd" : "#eee"
          }}
        />
      );
    }

    setGridCells(newGridCells);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="GridContainer" className="colored-grid" style={{
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(19, 1fr)",
      width: "380px",
    }}>
      {gridCells}
    </div>
  );
}
```